# How to reconnect vpn when the network status change from cellular to wifi?

Tags: ios, swift, vpn, networkextension

I am developing a vpn app using the network extension provided by apple. To achieve the ability of auto vpn reconnecting, I use the 'Connect on demand' feature of the extension, so that even the the phone didn't have network for a while, it will auto reconnect to my vpn server if the network recovers.

However, when my app is using cellular(4G) to connect to the vpn and I try to switch on the wifi, I find that the app is continually using the cellular to connect to the vpn but not using the wifi. Can I ask for the method to switching the network form cellular to wifi when connecting to the vpn?

---

Some websites say that adding observer to the `defaultPath` of the `PacketTunnelProvider` can observe the changes of network status and adding the following codes to restart the vpn tunnel. So that the phone can use wifi to reconnect to my vpn service.

```
NSLog("Network Environment Changed")
let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(1 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.startTunnelWithOptions(nil){_ in}
}
```

However, even I use the code above, my app cannot restart the vpn tunnel when the network status changes from cellular to wifi.

Hope anyone can answer my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `func cancelTunnelWithError(_ error: Error?)` to stop the tunnel,
As you are also using **'Connect on demand'** tunnel will automatically established on next network call.

To detect the network changes you can use **Rechibility** Class

Comment: Does Reachability fire on VPN changes?

Comment: YES, it will get fire.